# Smalltalk - Dictionary equivalent that takes alphanumeric as key?

Tags: smalltalk

Is there a Dictionary equivalent that will accept alphanumerics as the key? After spending some time on here getting you guys to help with assigning UUID values, I now realize that Dictionaries only take integers. I had planned on using the UUID as the key.

My design is for a General Ledger - my ledger member is initialized as `ledger := Dictionary new`, and I had hoped on doing something along the lines of:

```
postTransaction: GLEntry
    ledger at: GLEntry UID put: GLEntry
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Dictionary can use anything you like as a key.  Using Strings for keys in a Dictionary is quite common.  For example, in Dolphin Smalltalk v6.x evaluating the following:

```
d := Dictionary new.

d
  at: 'a' put: 'a string';
  at: 'b' put: 'b string';
  at: 'c' put: 'c string'.

Transcript
  show: (d at: 'a'); cr;
  show: (d at: 'b'); cr;
  show: (d at: 'c'); cr
```

will result in

```
a string
b string
c string
```

being shown in the Transcript window.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Weird, I don't know why I was getting the error I was... but it said  something about indexing with a non-integer. Anyways, it's working now somehow - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

@ctote You'll get that message if you attempt to use raw `#at` or `#at:put:` with any other object than integers. Your problem was probably somewhere else and not directly with dictionaries.

And funnyly enough we just had a stack trace with that error:

```
Error(Exception)>>signal:
  signalerText: 'only integers should be used as indices'
ByteString(Object)>>error:
  aString: 'only integers should be used as indices'
ByteString(Object)>>errorNonIntegerIndex
ByteString(Object)>>at:
  index: '2'
ByteString>>at:
  index: '2'
  #2: Character`
```

As you can see, someone tries to access a character in the string with `'2'` which is a string and therefore cannot be used to index the string collection.